# I need ethernet controller driver, PCI bus for Presario 6010US

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, network-adapter

Hi I am unable to connect to the internet.  ,Just installed the OS XP Pro and the device manager has a yellow question mark  for controller driver, PCI bus.  My network connection shows I am connected to a firewalled network with zero packets sent and received.  I checked HP.COM, with no luck.   Please advise what I should do.
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [page on HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=228&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=94026) for that model it uses an nVidia nForce chipset.

It is likely that the LAN chip will not be recognized properly until you have installed the [nVidia chipset](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=pv-45323-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=228&product=94026) software first.

Then install the [LAN driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=36440&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=228&product=94026)